# Which numbers will iterate to others under the Collatz iteration?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, conjectures, collatz-conjecture

I have a question about the Collatz conjecture and how some numbers merge trajectories.

Take the standard map:

$$C(n) =
\begin{cases}
n/2,  & \text{if $n \equiv 0$ mod $2$} \\
3n+1, & \text{if $n \equiv 1$ mod $2$}
\end{cases}$$

Suppose we have a minimal counterexample to the Collatz conjecture, $k \equiv 1 \text{ mod } 3 \in \Bbb{Z^+}$ (ignoring multiples of $3$ for now). Can it be proven that $k$ must join trajectories with any number of the form $k+3m+1$, such that $6m+1<k$? This last condition may seem a bit strange but it is needed so that smaller values of $k$ will suit this.

For example, if $m = 1$, can it be proven that $k+4$ will merge with $k$, for all, sufficiently large $k \equiv 1 \text{ mod } 3$? If that doesn't work, what about $m=2$?

To sum up, will the trajectory of $k+4$ or $k+7$ etc. ever meet the trajectory of $k$?
As always, help will be much appreciated, though it will be unlikely that anything will come from this.

Comment: If you could show that, would it not be fairly elementary to prove the Collatz conjecture? In which case, it probably is going to be a big ask for someone to post a solution. It might be better to ask for current literature rather than a solution?

Comment: This looks like an equivalent version of asking wether sub bitstrings will join local trajectories, like a fractal where the nodes are connected to a root or something like this. I found it rather obscure to know how to proof things with this.

Comment: @stuartstevenson Why would it be a fairly elementary thing to prove the conjecture?

Comment: @NaturalNumberGuy I believe this has a clear relationship with the collatz conjecture.

Comment: @Roskiller I don't know yet. I am also trying to figure this out. And it is not an easy task. Maybe the solution is simple, but its not easy to get to the proof, if it exists.

Comment: @NaturalNumberGuy would just iterating different forms work?

Comment: @Roskiller I do not know. The approach I am taking does not look like the forms you provided. Im suggesting to use $\pmod 8$, and also one extra parity bit that gives different outputs for the tribble-inputs. Im working from the ground up trying to build one or more complex statements from simple logical statements.

Comment: I don't know if what I just said made any sense. The point is to look at a small window looking at the bits of the number being processed. I.e do a sliding window and read each lump of bits based on some rules performing operations and doing some output(s).